# JPanel layout issue: by proportion / ratio of space

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I am new to programming and I am making a simple school project. I am trying make everything dynamically. I have two `JPanel` containers which I need to separate 1:5 in one `JFrame`. But I can't find the suitable layout.

How to assign space for the panels according to a 1:5 ratio?

Comment: Sounds like you may be asking a possible [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type question. Please tell us what this GUI will be used for including the function of the two JPanels. Also please show pertinent code.

Comment: In addition to the advice of @HovercraftFullOfEels, provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridBagLayout` gives you the 'weight' attribute. The first panel could have weight=1 and the second panel weight=5.

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

There are also some working examples:

[GridBagLayoutDemo.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridBagLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java)